# How do I use this component with typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

I've tried to use this [`PropertyGrid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-web-ui-property-grid) with:

```
  <property-grid id="pg1"></property-grid>
```

but I got the error:

```
Property 'property-grid' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

importing:

```
import  'clean-web-ui-property-grid';
```

doesn't solve it either. I've tried to make it using a function like:

```
const createPropertyGrid = (
  id: string,
  config: CleanPropertyGrid.PropertyGridConfig,
  options: CleanPropertyGrid.PropertyGridOptions,
  data: any
) => {
  const propertyGridWrapper = document.getElementById(
    id
  ) as CleanPropertyGrid.PropertyGrid;
  const propertyGrid = document.createElement(
    "property-grid"
  ) as CleanPropertyGrid.PropertyGrid;
  propertyGrid.id = "pg" + id;
  propertyGrid.config = config;
  propertyGrid.options = options;
  propertyGrid.selectedObject = data;
  propertyGridWrapper.innerHTML = "";
  propertyGridWrapper.appendChild(propertyGrid);
};
```

doesn't work either. How do I fix this? [here's a live](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-dewdney-963frt?file=/src/PropertyGrid.tsx:243-834) example

Comment: `<property-grid id="pg1"></property-grid>` Where is this code? In an html file, or in a react JSX?

Comment: @NicholasTower in a react jsx

Comment: it's a web component not JSX/react  so I don't this can be used inside react. If it did, then would be like this```import {PropertyGrid} from 'clean-web-ui-property-grid'; <PropertyGrid />```

Comment: seems i have to give up `clean-web-ui-property-grid` and find something else... which is sad because the was the closest i could get so far in terms of getting a .NET's PropetyGrid-like.

Comment: This library has `6`! downloads. Usually, anything below `50000` isn't used

Comment: Try https://cocopon.github.io/tweakpane/ or alternatives

Comment: @KonradLinkowski You right, but it was my poor keywords I guess, I did search for a property grid like and pretty much nothing up-to-date show up. Tweakpane seems really good. I think i'll just use this one. The version for react, useTweaks doesn't seem to have  many downloads either. Maybe i'll just stick to Tweakpane  version for npm and create the component with javascript/typescript code.